# How to add custom field to wordpress page everytime user uploads new image in WP visual editor?

Tags: dashboard, visual-editor

I have been hunting in GOOGLE for a long time. I want to add custom field whenever user uploads new image in page or post. Is there any hooks or filters that can be used to detect new image upload in WordPress.

I am new to WP and I want to have this done. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When an image is uploaded via the media editor the action hook `add_attachment` is triggered, with the `ID` of the attachment passed as the parameter. You can get full post data for the attachment using the `ID` to determine the `ID` of the post/page the image is attached to (stored in the `post_parent` property). Example code:

```
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'GoWP_wpse156258' );
function GoWP_wpse156258( $ID ) {
  $attachment = get_post( $ID );
  $post_id = $attachment->post_parent;
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'your_meta_key', 'your_meta_value' );
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you karpstrucking, but when you create new post, how does the  `ID`   comes. Second thing is how to get ID of the image being uploaded.